# How to update the dictionary from the user input and sort according to values using python?

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, enumeration

I have dictionary below

> {0: {'STATE': 'AL',
>      'POPULATION': '151449859682',
>     'TOP_CITY': '1',
>     'RANK': '1'},
>    1: {'STATE': 'NY',
>     'POPULATION': '8955557',
>     'TOP_CITY': '6',
>     'RANK': '2'},
>    2: {'STATE': 'CA',
>     'POPULATION': '7123215',
>     'TOP_CITY': '10',
>     'RANK': '3'},
>    3: {'STATE': 'PH',
>     'POPULATION': '68557813',
>     'TOP_CITY': '11',
>     'RANK': '4'},
>    4: {'STATE': 'IN',
>     'POPULATION': '7678676',
>     'TOP_CITY': '14',
>     'RANK': '5'}}

I want to sort according to RANK in descending by asking from the user input

```
value2sort= input('Enter the value to sort')
```

> RANK

```
parameter= input('asc for ascending order and desc for descending order')
```

> desc

expected out is below

> {4: {'STATE': 'IN',
>     'POPULATION': '7678676',
>     'TOP_CITY': '14',
>     'RANK': '5'},
>    3: {'STATE': 'PH',
>     'POPULATION': '68557813',
>     'TOP_CITY': '11',
>     'RANK': '4'},
>    2: {'STATE': 'CA',
>     'POPULATION': '7123215',
>     'TOP_CITY': '10',
>     'RANK': '3'},
>    1: {'STATE': 'NY',
>     'POPULATION': '8955557',
>     'TOP_CITY': '6',
>     'RANK': '2'},
>   0: {'STATE': 'AL',
>      'POPULATION': '151449859682',
>     'TOP_CITY': '1',
>     'RANK': '1'}}

Comment: dictionaries are unsorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sorted` with a `dict()` constuctor and then pass the values from your input into sort, you could setup a dictionary that can pass the arguments for `True/False` to handle `asc/desc`

```
value = input('Enter the value to sort: ')
param = input('Enter "asc" for ascending and "desc" for descending order: ')
order = {'asc': False, 'desc': True}

d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[1][value]), reverse=order[param]))
print(d)
```

> ```
> Enter the value to sort: RANK
> Enter "asc" for ascending and "desc" for descending order: desc
> {4: {'STATE': 'IN', 'POPULATION': '7678676', 'TOP_CITY': '14', 'RANK': '5'}, 3: {'STATE': 'PH', 'POPULATION': '68557813', 'TOP_CITY': '11', 'RANK': '4'}, 2: {'STATE': 'CA', 'POPULATION': '7123215', 'TOP_CITY': '10', 'RANK': '3'}, 1: {'STATE': 'NY', 'POPULATION': '8955557', 'TOP_CITY': '6', 'RANK': '2'}, 0: {'STATE': 'AL', 'POPULATION': '151449859682', 'TOP_CITY': '1', 'RANK': '1'}}
> ```

Comment: didn't get proper output for other values. Enter the value to sort: TOP_CITY
Enter "asc" for ascending and "desc" for descending order: asc 'TOP_CITY': '6' is coming last of the dictionary.

Comment: @user1464878 ty it needs to be `int(x[1][value])`, fixed

Comment: @MakbulHussain, take a peek at the update and make sure to inclue `int` in sort